# Insert only unique records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I ran the below query in SQL to insert records (this is just a snippet)

```
insert into list_member (list_id, list_int_value , list_float_value , list_decimal_value , list_varchar_value, list_datetime_value, modified_by, asof_time, do_not_audit)
select 42, null, null, security_id, null, null, 10, null, null
from security
 where not exists(select user_id_4 from list_member.user_id_4 where list_member.user_id_4  = security.user_id_4)
 and deleted = 0 and user_id_4 in
(
'ES0125220311',
'ES0132105018',
'ES0167050915'
)
```

Now I have another list to insert, but only want to insert new records.

I'm unsure where to insert the additional 'where' clause so that it doesn't insert duplicates.  I've come up with the below (which in theory should only add the final record), but the additional where clause in bold is likely wrong ...

```
insert into list_member (list_id, list_int_value , list_float_value , list_decimal_value , list_varchar_value, list_datetime_value, modified_by, asof_time, do_not_audit)
select 42, null, null, security_id, null, null, 10, null, null
from security
 **where not exists(select user_id_4 from list_member.user_id_4 where list_member.user_id_4  = security.user_id_4)**
 and deleted = 0 and user_id_4 in
(
'ES0125220311',
'ES0132105018',
'ES0167050915',
'ES0123456789'
)
```

Anyone able to assist?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: "the additional where clause in bold is likely wrong". Why do you say that?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I was getting syntax errors, but I have since changed it to get it working now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this instead

```
left join list_member 
   on list_member.list_id = 42 and list_member.list_decimal_value  = security.security_id
```

Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use corelated query as follows:

```
insert into list_member (list_id, list_int_value , list_float_value , list_decimal_value , list_varchar_value, list_datetime_value, modified_by, asof_time, do_not_audit)
select 42, null, null, security_id, null, null, 10, null, null
from security s
where not exists
  (select 1 from list_member l where l.user_id_4  = s.user_id_4)
 and deleted = 0 and user_id_4 in
(
'ES0125220311',
'ES0132105018',
'ES0167050915',
'ES0123456789'
)
```